# Objective C: Using code to add a toolbar to a UITableView (within a Navigation Controller)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I managed to add a toolbar at the bottom of my UITableView using the code below:

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 50);


//Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
[toolbar sizeToFit];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

However when I try to switch back to the first page of the navigation controller, the toolbar at the bottom of the page is still displayed. How can I ensure that the toolbar is only shown on the UITable View and not any other views in the navigation controller?

Thanks in advance.

Zhen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your TableViewController implement:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;
}
```